# After migration to react-native 61 the developer menu on emulator looks differrent

Tags: react-native

After migration to react-native 61 from 59 the developer menu in emulator looks different and when click on debug it is show me an error[image]
[image]

Comment: System:
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700B CPU @ 3.20GHz
Memory: 5.41 GB / 32.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.0, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
Xcode: 11.0/11A419c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Start Packager build phase manually with the following script and bundler is up and running:
export RCT_METRO_PORT="${RCT_METRO_PORT:=8081}"
echo "export RCT_METRO_PORT=${RCT_METRO_PORT}" > "${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env"
if [ -z "${RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER+xxx}" ] ; then
if nc -w 5 -z localhost ${RCT_METRO_PORT} ; then
if ! curl -s "http://localhost:${RCT_METRO_PORT}/status" | grep -q "packager-status:running" ; then
echo "Port ${RCT_METRO_PORT} already in use, packager is either not running or not running correctly"
exit 2
fi
else
open "$SRCROOT/../node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command" || echo "Can't start packager automatically"
fi
fi

reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25585

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why the app does not connect. You have to be on the same network or there might be an issue with the adb. Can you please refer to this [webpage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) for more clarity on how to run the app on device or simulator. It helped me out a lot while having issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ))) but what I am concern the most that the developer menu is looks different, "Debug" instead of "Debug JS remotly", there is no "Enable hot reloading" option. It it Looks like the native menu may be, and the title is contains. React JSI. This is an IOS emulator, not Android.

Comment: I am not sure about the 'Debug JS remotely' option in RN 0.60+ but for the hot reloading they have removed it because they have a better reloading JS engine which is faster and more reliable than live or hot reloading.